# Hide a Site Column in NewForm and EditView

Tags: development, site-column

I have created a custom site column. I have added this to my custom content type that inherits from the document content type. I wish to hide a field on the edit and new forms. I have the following code:

```
  <Field
  ID="{58EB1D2B-9EF6-46EA-9EC3-C98516D73791}"
  Name="test"
  DisplayName="test"
  Group="test"
  Type="Note"
  AppendOnly="True"
  UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="True"
  ShowInNewForm="False"
  ShowInEditForm="False"
  ShowInViewForms="True"  
  SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
    >
  </Field>
```

I then add this to my content type using

```
<FieldRef ID="{58EB1D2B-9EF6-46EA-9EC3-C98516D73791}" Name="test" DisplayName="test" />
```

The problem is that the field is still being displayed on the new and edit form. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use `TRUE` & `FALSE` rather than `True` & `False`. Changing to all capitals works wonders.